# How can I create a application launcher for a .sh file for jar file?

Tags: launcher

I have a program (name.jar file)
http://sourceforge.net/projects/yading/?source=recommended
that is started by running a double-click  name.sh file
How can I create a application launcher for a .sh file for jar file?

But it doesn't work launcher: `gnome-terminal -x sh -c /path/to/script/name.sh`

right click on panel to create ..  no work !
What should I do?

Comment: One alternative to alacarte (see the reply of To Do) is MenuLibre. pch

Answer (score 5):

First you have to make sure that the script file (.sh) is executable.

### Make the script executable

In Nautilus, right-click it, select properties, permissions. Make sure that "executable" is ticked.

Now if you double-click the file you should be able to run the program.

### Step 2: Create launcher

There two ways to do that.

#### The easy way

Install alacarte from Ubuntu software center or type `sudo apt-get install alacarte` in a terminal.
Then open the "Main Menu" application and create a new launcher for your script.

#### A more complex way

You may create a .desktop file for your script by copying and modifying one of the files in /usr/share/applications.

You may save the file in ~/.local/share/applications/

A nice guide for creating .desktop files can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .desktop file

Open a terminal and in it type:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/yading
```

In it put some information, following this format:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=yaDing
Exec='<path of where your .sh file is saved>'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon='<path to an image if you want an icon>'
Categories=<relevant categories, see below, separated with ;>
```

Then save it and it should work.

[Relevant Categories](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html)

Answer (score 0):

Op posted:

I solved this problem. STEP1 You just have to write a script

```
!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/translators/yaDing/

sh yaDing.sh
```

STEP2

```
chmod +x yourscript.sh
```

Launcher:

сommand: `/path/to/yourscript`